# Error de Compilacion Interface Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs-2.0, typescript

solicito de su ayuda debido a que he creado una interface con un campo boolean y me esta generando un error de compilación el cual he buscado y no se como solucionar

**`Interface:`**

```
export interface Empresa {
       key$ ? : string;
       nombre : string;
       nit : number;
        estado : boolean;
}
```

**`Componente:`**

```
empresa : Empresa = {
  nombre: "Mi Empresa",
  nit   : 123245566577,
  estado: true
};
```

**Error generado**: src/app/componentes/empresas/empresas.component.ts (16,5): Type '{ nombre: string; nit: number; estado: boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'Empresa'. Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'estado' does not exist in type 'Empresa'.

Answer (score 0):

Trata de declarar tu propiedad estado de tipo any: `estado: any;` y veamos si es problema de lo que le estás mandando o algo más, iba a comentar pero aun no tengo suficiente reputación jaja.

Comment: No funciona ya lo intente, funciona cuando le quito el elemento estado

Comment: Prueba a reinstalar Typescript , hay problemas con esto en algunas versiones:.  uninstall typescript ///
npm uninstall -g typescript ///
npm install typescript